# In this code read an integer N, I'm trying to print 123...N as output,#Note that (...)represents the values in between

Tags: python-3.x

I've the code ,
but I'm trying to use list  in my code,,I want to assemble the output and print them with list comprehension .

```
   for n in range(1,n+1):
       p=str(n)
       print(end=p)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
count = 10
for n in range(1, count):
  print(n)
```

I don't know if this is what you want but this will count until it reaches whatever the count variable equals.

hope I helped